# error ssl with threads

Tags: c, multithreading, ssl

I have the following code (some irrelevant parts were removed)

```
SSL_METHOD *meth = NULL;
SSL_CTX *ctx = NULL;
SSL *ssl = NULL;
BIO *sbio;
//open socket
int sock = open_port(ip,80);
if(sock == -1)
    return -1;
meth=SSLv23_client_method();
OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms();
ctx=SSL_CTX_new(meth);
/* Connect the SSL socket */
ssl=SSL_new(ctx);
sbio=BIO_new_socket(sock,BIO_NOCLOSE);
SSL_set_bio(ssl,sbio,sbio);
if(SSL_connect(ssl)<=0)
{
    SSL_free(ssl);
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
    return -1;
}

//ssl write & read part

SSL_shutdown(ssl);
SSL_free(ssl);
SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
//close socket
close(sock);
```

this is the function which every thread is calling for ssl connection and it works fine except that after running for a while I get the following error:

```
*** glibc detected *** test: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0xc4813440 ***
*** glibc detected *** test: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x096008b0 ***
```

***Which functions between SSL_free and SSL_CTX_free should I not use it ? Or the error is from somewhere else?***

Comment: The error doesn't appear to be in this code.

Comment: I tried the program without ssl and it's working perfectly and I don't get that error. So it has to be related to the ssl part somehow

Comment: and it doesn't appear all the time, only when I run more than 3 threads. without ssl I can run 100 without seeing that error

Comment: (1) Does the exact code above produce these errors? i.e. without the 'write & read part'? (2) Are these all local variables? (3) Are you calling `OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms()` in all the threads? which doesn't seem like it would be right. (4) Are you using a new SSL CTX in every thread?

Comment: 1) yes 2)yes and some I pass using args struct. 3) yes 4) yes

Comment: could it be because of point 3 and 4 ?

Comment: (3) doesn't sound right, I would change that, do it once. You should also use the same SSL_CTX throughout, rather than a new one per connection.

Comment: thanks a lot, I will try your hints. One more thing ... shall I use same CTX even if there are different IPs ? I mean should I define it in main()?

Comment: You should be able to use the same CTX for all connections. It's just a repository of certificates, cipher suites, and SSL sessions.